# cannot resolve symbol 'editText'

Tags: android

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I just started Android prog! so i am following this guide "Start Another Activity" fro google: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html 
Error occurs in this line         EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
In the "(R.id.editText)" part! 
so if someone can explain why & how am getting this error it will be greately helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `R.id.editText` will come from a `View` you've added in the layout for your `Activity`. Make sure you have an `<EditText>` there with an `id` of `editText`.

Comment: Thank you i identified the mistake was with the symbol name. It was editText2!

Answer (score 15):

I'm coming to this late, but adding this for those who find this searching for the answer.  Here's the heart of the "cannot resolve symbol 'editText'" problem.  In activity_main.xml, when creating the text edit box, the editor may append a number to the id:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
```

If you either remove the number, or edit the reference in MainActivity.java to match it, it works.

Note, if you remove the number, then you need to also remove it (in the same file) at:

```
<Button
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
```

as well, or the contraints won't connect.

*Really* something they should have noted in the tutorial.

On the flip side, I think I learned more from figuring this out than the rest of the tutorial so far.

Comment: 2018 and it is still there :/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help us out. 2019 and it still helped me, friend. :)

Comment: Helped me in 2020! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because you have't imported fallowing

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: But i imported all that!

Comment: okay can you attach xml file of your activity of sendMessage method?

Comment: Thank you i identified the mistake was with the symbol name. It was editText2!

Answer (score 0):

Just import the following.

import android.widget.EditText;

that will correct the error. cause this happens to me too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings(ctrl+alt+S) and under editor-> General->Auto Import

Ensure all the check boxes are checked in that.
Select "ALL" from the insert imports on paste drop down menu.

Apply. OK.

Answer (score 0):

The "editText" changes at some point. You need to change the "editText" to correspond to the id.

To find the id, under "attributes" in the activity_main.xml file, you'd find the id there. Change the "editText" to correspond to the one in the box.